# UnityでボタンONでフラグを立てる方法

Tags: unity2d

Unity初心者です。2Dゲームを作っています。プレイヤーがスタート地点から出発し、複数あるボタンすべてを押して戻ってきたらクリアという内容です。

●やりたいこと
・ボタンを押したときにフラグのようなものを立たせる
・プレイヤーがスタート地点の場所に戻ってきたとき、
-- if フラグの数がボタンの数と一致すればシーン遷移
-- else エラーを表示

この場合、
質問1:ボタンという機能をONしたときのフラグ？トリガーはどのようなものがあるんでしょうか。
質問2:Playerにアタッチしたmove.csの中で,スタート地点に戻ったときに、ボタンのフラグを参照するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか